# How to write a image uploaded by Mongodb GridFS onto ImageView

Tags: android, mongodb, android-imageview, gridfs

I have uploaded a image using Mongodb GridFS and now I want to show this image in the ImageView of android application.
My code for showing is

```
String bitmap = "/mnt/sdcard/image.png"
GridFS myContracts = new GridFS(myDatabase, "contracts");
GridFSDBFile file = myContracts.findOne("smithco");
file .writeTo(bitmap);
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmap));
```

I am trying to write this file into image.png and then trying to upload this file onto imageView but it is not working. Now I want to show this "file" in ImageView and I have no idea how to do that. And is there any other way to show the image instead of saving it to a file. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your image in the applications cache directory if you only need it temporarily.here is the code:

`

```
GridFS gfs = new GridFS(db);
ObjectId fileId = new ObjectId("your_object_id");

GridFSDBFile gfsFile = gfs.find(fileId);
File outFile;
RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
Context context = (Context) v.getContext();
outFile = File.createTempFile("xyz", null, context.getCacheDir());
gfsFile.writeTo(outFile);
ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(outFile);

iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
outFile.delete();`
```